# Python download URL from clipboard

Tags: python, url, clipboard

I am trying to download the URL that is contained in the clipboard, but i can not find a way to prevent downloading the same page over and over again. This is what i tried, but i get the error `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` what does this mean? it say that the error is on line 13, this is where it checks to see if the URL is valid.

```
import time
import os
import urllib

basename = "page"
extension = ".html"
count=0
old_url = ""

while(1):
    time.sleep(1) #check clipboard every second
    clipboard = os.system("pbpaste") # get contents of clipboard
    if clipboard[:4] == "http" and clipboard != old_url: # check if valid URL and is diffrent
        while os.path.exists(basename+str(count)+extension): # Create new name
            count=count+1
        old_url = clipboard
        name=basename+str(count)+extension
        data=urllib.urlopen(clipboard).read() #get page data
        file(name, "wb").write(data) # write to file
```

Comment: What line does that error occur on?

Comment: @ChristianTernus line 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
clipboard = os.system("pbpaste")
```

Here's why:

```
In [3]: ?os.system
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function system>
Docstring:
system(command) -> exit_status

Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.
```

os.system returns the *exit status* of the command, not the stdout of the command.

Try the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module instead:

```
import subprocess
clipboard = subprocess.check_output('pbpaste', shell=True)
```

Bear in mind, though, that it may be blank (or have less than five characters), which will cause your program to crash when you do `clipboard[:4]`. Best practice is to check the length of a sliceable object before slicing it: `if (len(clipboard) > 4)`, or better yet, `if (clipboard.startswith('http'))`.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, I did not suspect it was a result of how i read the clipboard.